# Convert a row to a list in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Is that possible to do that? All the data in my dataframe(~1000 cols) are Doubles and I'm wondering whether I could turn a row of data to a list of Doubles?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `toSeq` method on the Row and then convert the type from `Seq[Any]` to `Seq[Double]`(if you are sure the data types of all the columns are Double):

```
val df = Seq((1.0,2.0),(2.1,2.2)).toDF("A", "B")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: double, B: double]

df.show
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|1.0|2.0|
|2.1|2.2|
+---+---+

df.first.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]]
// res1: Seq[Double] = WrappedArray(1.0, 2.0)
```

In case you have String type columns, use `toSeq` and then use `map` with pattern matching to convert the *String* to *Double*:

```
val df = Seq((1.0,"2.0"),(2.1,"2.2")).toDF("A", "B")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: double, B: string]

df.first.toSeq.map{ 
    case x: String => x.toDouble
    case x: Double => x 
}
// res3: Seq[Double] = ArrayBuffer(1.0, 2.0)
```

Comment: I'm sorry it looks like my dataframe has all the numbers but in String format... Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can do some type conversion with `map` and pattern matching, see the update.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `dataframe` with `doubles` which you want to convert into `List` of `doubles`, then just convert the `dataframe` into `rdd` which will give you `RDD[Row]` you can covert this to `List` as

```
dataframe.rdd.map(_.toSeq.toList)
```

You will get `list of doubles`